# extract a prefix and multiple subsequent matches

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

## My Problem

I have a line that contains a prefix followed by one or more matched patterns. For example, the prefix is a letter followed by one or more numbers separated by spaces:

```
s='A 3 4 5'
```

I would like to find a regex pattern that would extract both the prefix and the repeated patterns.

## What Have I Tried

```py
s='''A 3 4 5'''
reg = re.compile(r'''
    ^(\w)       # Prefix
    (
        \s*     # Space separator
        (\d+)   # Pattern
        \s*     # Space separator
    )*
''', re.VERBOSE)
print(reg.findall(s))
```

However, it only finds the prefix and a single match:

```
[('A', '5', '5')]
```

The matched pattern appears twice because I have two groups - one containing the pattern itself and one containing the pattern with its separators.

## My Question

**How can I retrieve a single prefix and multiple matched patterns separated by a given divider using a Python regex?**

Comment: Please provide a string which has repeated patterns inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will require a two-level regex. Here's an example way to do it:

```
>>> import re
>>> s='''A 3 4 5'''
>>> outer_match = re.match(r'^(?P<prefix>\w)(?P<suffix>(\s*\d+\s*)*)', s)
>>> outer_match.groupdict()
{'prefix': 'A', 'suffix': ' 3 4 5'}
```

Then to extract the suffix pieces:

```
>>> prefix = outer_match.group('prefix')
>>> suffixes = re.findall(r'\s*(?P<val>\d+)\s*', outer_match.group('suffix'))
>>> suffixes
['3', '4', '5']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky question, owing to the fact that once the regex engine matches and consumes the prefix `A`, it won't check it again.  Here is one workaround which avoids directly using regex:

```py
s = 'A 3 4 5'
prefix = re.findall(r'[A-Z]+', s)[0]
terms = re.sub(r'\b(\d+)\b', prefix + r'\1', s).split(' ')[1:]
print(terms)
```

This prints:

```
['A3', 'A4', 'A5']
```

If you don't already have the `s` input in the format given above, then you might have to do some massaging to arrive at this starting point before you consider the above answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use PyPi regex library:

```py
import regex
s='''A 3 4 5'''
reg = regex.compile(r'''
    ^(\w)       # Prefix
    (
        \s*     # Space separator
        (\d+)   # Pattern
        \s*     # Space separator
    )*
''', regex.VERBOSE)
m = regex.fullmatch(reg, s)
if m:
    res = []
    res.append(m.group(1))
    res.extend(m.captures(2))
    print(res)
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##jY5Ba8JAEIXv@ysGPGRXJdCqF8FDC56VCl6aCkuc6EI2O8xOaPrr49akOXdOM@97b3j0I/fQrPreeQoswHjDTsVdlmVvsII1bNKmkgq7geVl8ORq1PwLIM1FF98GhpnBkbFy3RNoNapQxPmIT2RLhIhk2UrgyaGL68IMD6wIcvPPrJmr1GM5djvvP94Pp71RfqpbtXXtrZR3ne4lRKNcBX77DDPG5Pv8@jtyS4TNVfv8xqEl/WLMhLCTAZWWpE2Kfh0psWskfY@m7x8).

**Results**:  `['A', ' 3 ', '4 ', '5']`.